# Ext.Ajax.request vs model.save cross origin cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, extjs, cross-domain, extjs6

I'm having an issue with `model.save` not sending the cookies back with my cross origin request, but `Ext.Ajax.request` has no issue sending back the cookies.  In our local development at work, we override the beforerequest on all Ajax requests (which includes model actions) to set [`withCredentials = true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-withCredentials) and [`useDefaultXhrHeader = false`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-useDefaultXhrHeader), which helps with CORS on a normal Ext.Ajax.request.

From what I understand, having a proxy of type `ajax` is similar to doing Ext.Ajax.request, and that's apparent because model.save hits the beforerequest (you'll see this in the example below).  You'll also notice in the example that the model.save sends an OPTIONS call first, and then never follows up with the POST (but that's most likely because of the server)... either way, OPTIONS instead of POST seems a little fishy.

Here's the [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/22oh):

```
Ext.Ajax.on({
    beforerequest: function (conn, options, eOpts) {
        console.log('here', conn, options)
        options.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;
        options.withCredentials = true;
    }
});
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['test'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'https://docs.sencha.com'
    }
});
var model = Ext.create('MyModel');
// This will fire off an OPTIONS call and not send the cookies
model.save();
// This will fire off with the POST and send the cookies
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'https://docs.sencha.com',
    method: 'POST'
});
```

Is there any way to get model.save to send the cookies to the cross domain?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't get around the `OPTIONS` request.

The browser will start sending an `OPTIONS` request once you add a payload to the POST request, like `model.save()` does. This also happens to your `Ext.Ajax.request` operation if you change it slightly to match the `model.save` operation:

```
// This will fire off an OPTIONS request.
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'https://docs.sencha.com',
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: {id: "MyModel-1"}
});
```

This `OPTIONS` request is a so-called "preflight request" intended to get the information from the server whether the server is allowing the actual cross-origin request. The server has to answer that positively, including Http Response Headers containing a set of CORS headers. `docs.sencha.com` does indeed answer the `OPTIONS` request, but it does not return the required headers, so you find an error message in the browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.sencha.com/?_dc=1499412133932. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.sencha.com' is therefore not allowed access.

As a counter-example, my CORS-enabled backend sends to the client the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With
```

- `Origin` contains all domains from which CORS requests may be sent, or * for all domains.
- `Methods` contains all allowed methods, you will need at least `OPTIONS, POST`.
- `Headers` contains all headers that your request may send to the server. Chrome console will tell you if you are missing one the browser expects; at least that's how I got to my list.

If these conditions are met on an `OPTIONS` request, the actual `POST` request will be sent; otherwise, you will find said error message in the browser console.

Comment: I don't understand why we can't make this act like a normal Ajax request... it clearly uses parts of a normal Ajax request, so what exactly is making this behave differently?  Is it the way the payload is handled?  Can't we change the headers of the model to send as form data?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mitchell Simoens over on the [Sencha Forums](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?353410), he helped me figure out the root cause of the issue, which is the proxy's writer.  I needed to create a custom writer in order to solve this issue.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/22pt):

```
Ext.define('Ux.data.writer.Json', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.writer.Json',
    alias  : 'writer.ux-json',

    config : {
        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} useJsonData
         * If {@link #allowSingle} is `true` and only one model is being
         * saved, this will control if the request will set the data using
         * `params` or `jsonData`.
         */
        useJsonData : false
    },

    writeRecords: function(request, data) {
        var me = this,
            root = me.getRootProperty(),
            transform = this.getTransform(),
            json, single;

        if (me.getExpandData()) {
            data = me.getExpandedData(data);
        }

        if (me.getAllowSingle() && data.length === 1) {
            // convert to single object format
            data = data[0];
            single = true;
        }

        if (transform) {
            data = transform(data, request);
        }

        if (me.getEncode()) {
            if (root) {
                // sending as a param, need to encode
                request.setParam(root, Ext.encode(data));
            } else {
                //<debug>
                Ext.raise('Must specify a root when using encode');
                //</debug>
            }
        } else if (single && !me.getUseJsonData()) {
            request.setParams(Ext.apply(request.getParams(), data));
        } else if (single || (data && data.length)) {
            // send as jsonData
            json = request.getJsonData() || {};

            if (root) {
                json[root] = data;
            } else {
                json = data;
            }

            request.setJsonData(json);
        }

        return request;
    }
});

Ext.Ajax.on({
    beforerequest: function (conn, options, eOpts) {
        console.log(options.url, options);

        options.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;
        options.withCredentials = true;
    }
});

Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['blah'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'https://docs.sencha.com',
        writer: {
            type: 'ux-json'
        }
    }
});

var model = Ext.create('MyModel', {
    blah : 2
});
model.save();

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'https://docs.sencha.com',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        blah: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried to reproduce, and an OPTIONS request is sent: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22ps https://i.imgur.com/mctp6JO.png

Comment: You didn't fully reproduce it... if you add `useDefaultXhrHeader = false` and `withCredentials = true`, it'll work, but there's another issue here, and I'm trying to figure it out... this all boils down to the model's writer and modifying that will actually fix the entire issue... I'll report back when I have a better solution.